# PHP doc question?

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

I was reading the doc on the imagefilter and was wondering what does it mean when it reads. What should I expect to see when either occurs?

`Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what it says.

If the function succeeds, it returns the boolean value `true`, and if it fails, the boolean value `false`.  You won't "see" anything unless you `echo` the result of the function, at which point the boolean value will be converted to a string, and then will read `true` or `false`.

You can use this value anywhere you need a boolean.  For example.... suppose I have a function, `myFunction()`, and it returns "true on success or false on failure" just like whatever function you are using.  You could do this:

```
if (myFunction()) {
    echo "The call to myFunction() succeeded!";
} else {
    echo "The call to myFunction() failed!";
}
```

Specifically in the case of your `imagefilter()` function, it doesn't return an image.  All of the work is done on the image referenced by the first parameter.  It only returns `true` or `false`, just like it says.